# owl-carousel 2 sync customization

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I'm using Two owl carousel sliders with one navigation for my bootstrap website. In the below code `prev` and `next` is working perfectly.

The problem that the `ondrag` and `owl-dots` functions are not working. When I click the dot and drag the first slider (`work-class1`) the second slider should slide same like `prev` and `next` arrow.

```js
var o2 = $('#work-class2')
o2.owlCarousel({
  items: 2,
  singleItem: true,
  loop: false,
  margin: 10,
  dots: false,
  pagination: false,
  nav: false,
  touchDrag: true,
  slideBy: 2,
  mouseDrag: false
});

var o1 = $('#work-class1');
o1.owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  singleItem: true,
  loop: false,
  margin: 0,
  //dots:false,
  pagination: false,
  nav: true,
  touchDrag: true,
  slideBy: 1,
  mouseDrag: true
});

var o1 = $('#work-class1'),
  o2 = $('#work-class2');
  
//Sync o2 by o1
o1.on('click onDragged', '.owl-next', function() {
  o2.trigger('next.owl.carousel')
});

o1.on('click dragged.owl.carousel', '.owl-prev', function() {
  o2.trigger('prev.owl.carousel')
});

//Sync o1 by o2
o2.on('click onDragged', '.owl-next', function() {
  o1.trigger('next.owl.carousel')
});

o2.on('click dragged.owl.carousel', '.owl-prev', function() {
  o1.trigger('prev.owl.carousel')
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next span,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev span,
.owl-carousel button.owl-dot {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.owl-dot span {
  display: block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background: #f00;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="owl-carousel work-class1" id="work-class1">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
        <img src="http://www.idaconcpts.com/wp-content/testing-website-optimization.png" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="owl-carousel work-class2" id="work-class2">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
        <img src="http://www.idaconcpts.com/wp-content/testing-website-optimization.png" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that works for what you need.  Basically, just changed the second carousel options into an object and referenced that to determine how many slides to switch the secondary carousel by with a translate.owl.carousel call.  It's also easily extendable should you want to add more slides into the secondary carousel.

```
var o2 = $('#work-class2')
var o2settings = {
  items: 2,
  singleItem: true,
  loop: false,
  margin: 10,
  dots: false,
  pagination: false,
  nav: false,
  touchDrag: true,
  slideBy: 2,
  mouseDrag: false
};
o2.owlCarousel(o2settings);
```

```
o1.on('translate.owl.carousel', function(e) {
  o2.trigger('to.owl.carousel',e.page.index * o2settings.slideBy);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ucfnjv5e/1/

Comment: Thank you so much. Must appreciated work. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to *changed.owl.carousel* event and then trigger [`to.owl.carousel`](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html#to-owl-carousel) to sync the carousels on *click*, *scroll* and *drag* :

```
// sync o2 on o1
o1.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
  o2.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [event.item.index == 0 ? 0 : 2]);
});
```

Note the calculation of *indices* depend on the no of items in the first and second carousel. See demo below and a [`codepen`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oVLgxM) to fiddle with:

```js
var o2 = $('#work-class2')
o2.owlCarousel({
  items: 2,
  singleItem: true,
  loop: false,
  margin: 10,
  dots: false,
  pagination: false,
  nav: false,
  touchDrag: true,
  slideBy: 2,
  mouseDrag: false
});

var o1 = $('#work-class1');
o1.owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  singleItem: true,
  loop: false,
  margin: 0,
  //dots:false,
  pagination: false,
  nav: true,
  touchDrag: true,
  slideBy: 1,
  mouseDrag: true
});

var o1 = $('#work-class1'),
  o2 = $('#work-class2');

// sync o2 on o1
o1.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
  o2.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [event.item.index == 0 ? 0 : 2]);
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next span,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev span,
.owl-carousel button.owl-dot {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.owl-dot span {
  display: block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background: #f00;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="owl-carousel work-class1" id="work-class1">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
        <img src="http://www.idaconcpts.com/wp-content/testing-website-optimization.png" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="owl-carousel work-class2" id="work-class2">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
        <img src="http://www.idaconcpts.com/wp-content/testing-website-optimization.png" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need the second carousel will slideby 2 currenty it will slideby 1 when I scroll the first slide.